# IE 11 is not showing Java applet in navigator.mimeTypes

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I have installed Java plugin in IE 11. (Java Plug-in 10.45.2 - 32-bit and 64-bit)
We detect for java compatibility with JavaScript in our site.

navigator.mimeTypes is used to get list of installed plugins.

But we cannot get type for Java applet (application/x-java-applet).

And because of that, we don't run java applet though it's installed.

Does anybody has faced such issue or suggest any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html) provided by Oracle.

### Update

The deployment toolkit is a JS based tool that checks the Java *installed in the browser.* It used to be useful for both (embedded) applet deployment as well as JWS apps (either embedded applets or free floating applets of frames).

But times change. Browser makers are moving or have moved to a 'plug-in free' web & the result is that that they are completely dropping support for applets in browsers. The upshot of that is that the *deployment toolkit script no longer works **at all** - for **any** use.*

**Further info.:** See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft introduced mimetypes in IE11 which means browser agnostic plugin detection of the Java plugin can now be used (IE11+ only of course). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Starting with IE11, the navigator object supports plugins and mimeTypes properties.

Unfortunately, the JRE/plugin installer does not support IE mimetypes as at 1.7.0_67 and 1.8.0_20. According to the above, it needs to register the mimetypes in the Windows registry.

> To support the new properties, plugins need to update the Registry when installed:
>
> 1. Under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList create a key using the name to be reported by the plugins property.
> 2. Create subkeys for each custom MIME type supported by the plugin, using the MIME type value as the name of the subkey.
> 3. For 64-bit environments, add the same Registry entries to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432\Microsoft\Internet
>      Explorer\NavigatorPluginsList.
> 4. Verify that unique MIME types are properly registered with the device loading the webpage, as well as the server hosting the webpage.

So, Microsoft finally joined the party, but Oracle have yet to arrive.

Until then use the problematic ActiveXObject (which reports disabled plugins as available).