# IE 11 can't find Java Plugin to run Applet

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, applet, activex

I have application build with Java Applets, which works fine for Windows 7 with IE 9. Now I'm trying move it to another environment. There is **Internet Explorer 11**.

To run applet I'm using [Oracle Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html) with latest version taken from https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt. But the script **doesn't detect Java Plugin**. It only redirects to page `java.com` (suggesting to download latest `JRE`).

But my browser has Java Plugin installed (here JRE 1.7.80):

[image]

There are also two **SSV Helpers** - maybe they cause the problem?

[image]

Java 8 (u144) cause the same problem.

**Question:**

*How to detect Java Plugin in IE 11 and run applet?*

*Is it problem with `deployJava.js` or IE 11 configuration?*

**More explanations:**

Oracle `deployJava.js` script uses such code to detect JRE version in IE ([deployJava source - lines 1172-1188](https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt)):

```
testUsingActiveX: function(version) {
    var objectName = 'JavaWebStart.isInstalled.' + version + '.0';

    // we need the typeof check here for this to run on FF/Chrome
    // the check needs to be in place here - cannot even pass ActiveXObject
    // as arg to another function
    if (typeof ActiveXObject == 'undefined' || !ActiveXObject) {
        log('[testUsingActiveX()] Browser claims to be IE, but no ActiveXObject object?');
        return false;
    }

    try {
        return (new ActiveXObject(objectName) != null);
    } catch (exception) {
        return false;
    }
},
```

Unfortunately, ActiveX seems to be limited, restricted or disabled in IE 11. This topic on [SO is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151999/ie11-prevents-activex-from-running)... anyone knows any details?

I run manually (in IE 11.1480 developer console) this code:

```
new ActiveXObject('JavaWebStart.isInstalled.1.8.0.0');
```

which returns:

> Automation server can't create object

But running the same code in a bit older IE 11.09600 returns object:

> [object] { }

I'm confused... Can Oracle do the script better?

**Specification:**

Internet Explorer 11, Version: 11.1480... Update Versions: 11.0.44

System: Windows Server

Java: tested with **1.8.144** and after **1.7.80**

Applets run by Oracle [deployJava.js](https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt)

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). (The deployment toolkit script no longer works.) BTW - I'm guessing you were the person that upvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498518/418556)? I've edited it to add an update..

Comment: Don't agree. Actually, the Java Plugin is installed in IE (see screenshots) but applets doesn't work. Moreover, second link you provide says: *"Oracle plans to deprecate the Java browser plugin in JDK 9."* So now it should work. Any idea? Any "dirty" hack to run applet?

Comment: *"Don't agree."* That's like not agreeing with gravity.. Whatever. Good luck with it. I'm done with trying to get applets to work.

Comment: As mentioned, Java Applet technology is being phased out. See white paper of 2018-03 from Oracle: [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a solution:

Applets requires **32-bit JRE** installed on client machine (and as IE Plugin). Or to be more specific IE ActiveX mechanism works only with 32-bit Java because all IE are 32-bit by default. There are also 64-bit IE version, but I don't try it.

I used the newest `JRE 1.8u144 32 bit`.

Some hints for anyone to make applets work (even in 2017):

1. Check Internet Explorer version (32- or 64-bit) - look at *Help* -> *About Internet Explorer*, if there is no 64-bit info, then you probably use 32-bit. Check also Windows Task Manager and search for *32 processes. More info in [other SO questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20118947/5162026).
2. Disable ActiveX Filtering may also help. But in my situation, this wasn't necessary because IE displays message which warn about running Java plugin and I just need to accept this.
3. I have disabled option: *Enable Protected Mode* on *Security* tab in *Internet Options* window (for *Internet zone*).

More information can be retrieved from this discussion:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/cannot-access-secure-website-that-requires-java/173f732b-7377-41f6-8c6f-2ae171f4da7a?auth=1

Comment: I had the same issue. It works when I installed the 32-bit JRE +1

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work with JRE 9 because oracle didn't released it's 32-bit version. I'm looking still looking for answers for JRE 9 64-bit.

Comment: GC Campus requires the 32-bit version installed. Thanks a ton @jsosnowski! This resolved it for me. +1

Comment: This is the answer, you saved my day. Thank you. This is so stupid when I using a 64bit OS but still have to install 32bit version to get Java work on IE 11. Holly crap.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer was useful. But we did an update to jre1.8.0_144. I reinstalled 32 bit JDK in my system which integrated a java plug-in 11.144.2 automatically as add on in my Internet explorer 11. Also I could see the architecture of the plugin as 32 bit and 64 bit.

Its good to download a 32 bit jre which will automatically configure the necessary add on. This fix made IE to run applets.